# For a positive integer n, is Math.random()*n >= n possible?

Tags: javascript, floating-point

According to [Why are floating point numbers inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate), floating point numbers has errors.

My question is, for a positive integer n, is it possible that Math.random()*n has errors such that its result becomes equals or greater than n?

Comment: Floating point doesn't have "errors" as the word is commonly used, just "error" in mathematical sense, or degree of inaccuracy. With that, a number less than 1 multiplied by a positive integer cannot result in a number greater or equal than `n`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If *n* is greater than the minimum positive normal number of the floating-point format, then `Math.Random()*n` < *n*.

(As [abacabadabacaba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2602809/abacabadabacaba) noted in a comment, if *n* is the minimum normal, e.g., 2<sup>−1022</sup> for IEEE-754 basic 64-bit binary, and `Math.Random` returns its maximum value, 1 − 2<sup>−53</sup>, then the product rounds to the minimum normal, so `Math.Random()*n` = *n*.)

A proof follows.

### Preliminaries

- In this answer, expressions written in `code format` refer to computed values. Expressions outside code format refer to exact mathematics. For any number *n*, `n` is the result of rounding *n* to the floating-point format. `a`•`b` is the exact mathematical product of `a` and `b` before floating-point rounding, and `a*b` is the floating-point result after rounding.
- IEEE-754 binary floating-point with rounding-to-nearest-ties-to-even is used. Some familiarity with IEEE-754 is required.
- ULP stands for Unit of Least Precision. It is the value of the least significant bit of the significand of a floating-point representation of a particular number.
- *p* is the number of bits in the significand of a floating-point representation. For IEEE-754 basic 64-bit binary floating-point, *p* is 53, but this proof applies to other widths.
- If *h* is the value represented by the high bit of the significand in a normal floating-point representation (due to scaling by the exponent), *h*•2<sup>1−*p*</sup> is the value represented by the low bit and is the ULP for the represented number, and *h*•2<sup>−*p*</sup> is ½ ULP and is the maximum change that can be produced by rounding any number in the range of this exponent to the floating-point format.
- By “*n* is in the normal range,” I mean `n` is normal. This means 2<sup>*m*</sup>•(1−2<sup>−*p*</sup>) ≤ *n* < 2<sup>*M*+1</sup>•(1−2<sup>−*p*</sup>), where *m* and *M* are the minimum and maximum exponents in the floating-point format (−1022 and 1023 for IEEE-754 64-bit binary floating-point).

### Lemma 0: Rounding is Weakly Monotonic

Given *a* < *b*, consider the results of rounding them to the floating-point format, `a` and `b` (using the round-to-nearest-ties-to-even rule).

Suppose `b` < `a`.

If `a` ≤ *a*, then `b` < `a` ≤ *a* < *b*. This is not possible because `b` is farther from *b* than `a` is, so *b* must round to `a` or a closer number, not to `b`. Conversely, if *a* < `a`, then *a* ≤ `b` < `a` or `b` < *a* < `a`. In the former case, *a* could not round to `a` as `b` is closer. In the latter case, if `a` ≤ *b*, then *b* cannot round to `b` since `a` is closer, and, if *b* < `a`, then *a* cannot round to `a` since `b` is closer.

So it cannot be that `b` < `a`; it must be that `a` ≤ `b`.

### Lemma 1: Floating-Point Multiplication is Weakly Monotonic

Multiplication by a positive number *y* is weakly monotonic, since, if
*x*<sub>0</sub> < *x*<sub>1</sub>, then *x*<sub>0</sub>•y < *x*<sub>1</sub>•y,
and Lemma 0 tells us that `x0*y` ≤ `x1*y`.

### Proof

Let *g* be the greatest possible result of `Math.Random()`. Since JavaScript’s `Math.Random()` returns a number in [0, 1), *g* is 1−2<sup>−*p*</sup>.

By Lemma 1, if `g*n` < *n*, any result *x* ≤ *g* of `Math.random()` satisfies `x*n` < *n*.

We will prove that `g*n` < `n` and then show this implies `g*n` < *n*.

Consider `g*n`. If `n` is exactly a power of two greater than the minimum normal number of the floating-point format, then `g`•`n` is exactly representable in the floating-point format, and there is no rounding, so `g*n` = (1−2<sup>−*p*</sup>)•`n` < `n`. If `n` is not a power of two, then `g`•`n` is (1−2<sup>−*p*</sup>)•`n` = `n` − `n`•2<sup>−*p*</sup>. The latter is less than `n` by more than ½ ULP of `n`, and so, when it is rounded to the floating-point format, it is rounded down, producing a result less than `n`. (Note this is not true for **any** number *n*, since `g*n` could be in the subnormal range, where an ULP may be larger than `n`•2<sup>1−*p*</sup>. However, we assume *n* is in the normal range, which is true for all positive integers up to the point where `n` overflows.)

Thus `g*n` < `n`. Finally, we consider the possibility that, when *n* is rounded to the floating-point format, the result `n` is greater than *n*, and this could lead to `g*n` > *n*. However, `g*n` < `n` requires that `g*n` be less than `n` by at least 1 ULP, but rounding *n* to `n` can increase the value by at most ½ ULP. So `g*n` < *n*.

Comment: This proof has an error: if _n_ = 2^m, then `g`•`n` is denormal (even though `n` is not) and in fact `g*n` = `n`.

Comment: @abacabadabacaba: Thanks, I noted the exception.

Answer (score 5):

`Math.random() * n` will not result in a number greater or equal to `n` because the `Math.random()` returns a floating point number `x` where `0 <= x < 1`. The documentation for the `Math.random()` function is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Comment: This is incorrect. `Math.random()` won't return 1, but the result of the multiplication may be rounded upward to `n`.

Comment: @Sneftel: It is correct, and there is a proof in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54767342/298225).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes, but only in very extreme cases.

It is possible for

```
Math.random()*n >= n
```

To return true in cases where n is extremely large.

Note that in these cases, the result will equal the chosen number n.

From the `Math.random()` [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#Examples):

> Note that as numbers in JavaScript are IEEE 754 floating point numbers with round-to-nearest-even behavior, the ranges claimed for the functions below (excluding the one for Math.random() itself) aren't exact. If extremely large bounds are chosen (253 or higher), it's possible in extremely rare cases to calculate the usually-excluded upper bound.

```
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

Although technically possible, this occurrence is so very rare as to be negligible

Comment: The documentation you cite considers `Math.random() * (max-min) + min`, which is different from `Math.random() * max`. For the case asked about in this question, it is not possible, per the proof in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54767342/298225).

Comment: That documentation seems misleading: large bounds aren't the only issue here. If you take `min = 1.0` and `max = 1.0 + 2**-52`, you'd expect `Math.random() * (max - min) + min` to give `max` roughly half the time.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add something that might be usesul to know, actually if `n` is set to [Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/POSITIVE_INFINITY) the condition becomes `true`:

```js
let posInf = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
console.log(Math.random(), posInf);
console.log(Math.random() * posInf >= posInf);
```